# To program a 64 bits based software, must I use a 64 bits IDE?

Tags: windows, linux, service, console, 64-bit

If I am writting a 64 bits application(console, service or visual) over Windows or Linux, whatever it was the language that I want to use(Java, C#, C++, C....), it's recommended or must I use a 64 bits based IDE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IDE doesn't matter as it's just a frontend to your development. The compiler must support 64 bit binary creation. In something like Visual Studio you would to go right click project and choose Settings->Platform->x86_64 (IIRC)

Answer (score 3):

No. All it matters is your IDE should have ability to use tools (compilers/linkers) create the binaries targetting 64 bits.